# Power shell command to disable the networking setting of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

In Azure Data Factory under the Settings options of "Networking", we have to disable the "Public Network Access", under the "Network access" option.
If the public network access is "Enabled" then it is Open to Internet, which states that - "All Networks, including Internet can access Data Factory".
And this is more threat of exposing the Data Factory to internet. For which we need a power-shell/AZ CLI command which will help us to disable the 'Public Network Access".

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is possible to do via PowerShell. Do you know you can use Integration runtimes and set the access policy to it, leaving your Public availability?

Comment: Why does it need to be powershell? Are you automatically deploying your ADF using Powershell? Have you already set up VNets and Private Endpoint for your data factory?

Comment: Hi @Anirudh Bragadeesan, we could use powersell command to get the data factory object, then set the property publicNetworkAccess to achieve that. Please see my answer. It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it with `properties.publicNetworkAccess`, please see the code bellow:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$a= Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DataFactory/factories -ResourceGroupName ChinaCXPTeam-Resources -ResourceName dfleon
$a.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled"
$a | Set-AzResource -Force
```

Here are the module versions I use:

[image]

Update:

This command also works well:

```
$a = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DataFactory/factories -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" -ResourceName "<datafactory-name>"
$a.Properties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "publicNetworkAccess" -Value "Disabled" -Force
$a | Set-AzResource -Force
```

Comment: In the $a object properties.publicNetworkAccess is not available. Because of that we are getting the below error.

Comment: In the $a.properties we are not able to find 'publicNetworkAccess' property. Because of that we are not able to set the value to it.

Comment: Error message-
 $a.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled"

SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "publicNetworkAccess": "The property 'publicNetworkAccess' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan which module version are you using?

Comment: @LeonYue Even I am looking for same solution, and there is no powerhsell command to change the network setting of data factory. Would be very helpful if it can be done,

Comment: @LeonYue We are using below PS version.
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.3
PSEdition                      Core
We are trying it from Azure Powershell itself & we are not getting any error related to the module.

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan  I will show you more details later.

Comment: @Leon Yue we have urgent requirement if you can help quick that will be great. Kindly let us know exactly how we can extract the property of 'publicNetworkAccess' from the $a object.

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan Please update the `Az.Account` and `Az.Resource` module to the latest version and try again.

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan Please try set it firstly on Portal, and then use the powershell again. When I first run the command, I got the same error.

Comment: Yes @Leon Yue The same command I updated and now with this script we are able to meet our requirements. It was great working with you Really appreciate. Thanks a ton.I resolved few hours back.

Comment: Marked as perfect answer.Thank you